# aws: Networking issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

While running ecs fargate task aws automatically stopped my task with error

```
There was an error while describing network interfaces.
The networkInterface ID 'eni-0c21gdfgerg' does not exist
```

My task was running for more than a day but now it suddenly stopped.

I checked that eni- and that eni is not existing.

How can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: let you start with Cloudtrail if you have it on, every change should have a log line there.

Comment: What logs should I look into cloudtrail?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like ecs fargate task have different stages and in `Deprovisioning` stage it deletes all the networking related stuff where network interface is also deleted.

Also I was viewing this task in `Stopped` stage that's why i was getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. "networkInterface ID 'eni-xx' does not exist. My exit code is 1. The application error.

This answer may not be for everyone. I was doing a Python project. It turns out I missed one dependency name in my requirement.txt.